# Error to upload SignInSignUp Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When trying to upload the SignUp_SignIn policy, in the policy validation process, the following error arose:

[image: Error Uploading Signin Signup custom policy]

Tried to add the following attribute in TrustFrameworkExtensions, but i kept getting the same error.

[image: TrustFrameworkExtensions Attribute]

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly formatted text, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: perhaps you should remove your input claim, since you want anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly allow insecure auth for your rest api technical profile.

Example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-restful-api-technical-profile

Add this item to the metadata section of your rest api technical profile.

```xml
<Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
```